# add marker to check if program is done updating the CSV file

Tags: java, groovy, opencsv

I have a program that outputs csv file and add entries continuously. My second program reads the csv file, I need an EOF marker that can be recognized by OpenCsv, once the eof marker is read my second program will then check for a new file.

I'm using OpenCsv, what is the better approach to achieve this?

Comment: Is it an option to save to a temporary file while working and when finished rename it to the name the second program expects?

Comment: It's adding entries continuously?  Forever?